# Linear Layout Or Relative Layout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

someone said people must use relative layout when make android app. Because if use linear layout, app's screen doesn't adjust device screen. (I mean width and height doesn't adjust). But if I use relative layout, it's make me annoyed when I set image. Is opinion which I hear right ?

Comment: all answers is good. But I must choose one answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my view i would prefer RelativeLayout as parent.
And i go for LinearLayout for all the inner layouts where i can use
`android:orientation` and `android:height` as `match_parent/fill_parent` that will fill only the space available with in LinearLayout.
I never prefer to use `dp` values for `android:height` and `android:width`

Answer (score 1):

Both have it's own pros and cons. Both can adjust without any problem to device screen. What really matter are the views that you will put inside of them (children) and how they will be organized.

In addition to that, you may want to modify the gravity, margin, padding, alignment or any other to achieve a desired result.

Answer (score 1):

I'll go with Relative Layout as we can set different views easily in this layout.